# Activex Buttons show up twice and one set is larger than the other and floating to the right

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

This is such an odd issue and I'm having a lot of trouble troubleshooting it and I can't Google it in any way that makes sense.  We recently moved from Office 2012 to Office 365.

Office 365 all the buttons on a form I have built are showing up twice now.  They show up in the actual locations that I've put them but then they show up again, about twice the size of the original buttons and floating to the right of the document (past even the margin).

These "Floating buttons" (for lack of a better term), are the ones that actually work.  No idea why.  Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

[image: Picture of issue]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words....

Comment: I added a picture per your request.

Comment: If it happened after switching versions, go to File > Inspect Document and select "Check for Compatibility".

Comment: No Compatibility issues found when I tried, but thank you for the suggestion.